# Designing a product with USB Host and Device mode and connectors

Tags: usb-device, usb-host

I'm the product manager for a line where we are going to develop a new version that supports USB devices.  So the product will act as a host via USB 2.0.  However, the same product also needs to be able to be a device so as to allow a laptop to update its firmware and do configuration changes using software on the laptop.

The question is which type of connector to supply?  Normally as a device, we would supply a Type B.  For a Host Type A.  In this case, it can be both based on the use case.  Ideally we should have both a Type A and a Type B, and separate the power supply but the product has very little space available and its also waterproof so that complicates things.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could always move into the 21st century and use a Type-C ... just ignore the SuperSpeed lines ...

Comment: Or if not USB-C, what about micro-USB/On-The-Go?